# asp.net core web api...how to select my port?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written my first web API. I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1. I've also written a client (in WPF) that is meant to be paired with it. I'm a little confused about ports and how to choose one. When I hunt around online I see general advice about how to "pick a port that probably won't conflict etc." but this advice doesn't fill me with confidence.

Currently for testing purposes I've fixed the port number to some number and I've hardcoded it into the client so that it can communicate with the server via "http://localhost:someNumber/etc...". What happens if the server hosting my web api (Kestrel) is left to choose the port automatically? In this case the client doesn't know the port a priori...how can it communicate with it?

Comment: If you don't specify a port Kestrel will serve requests on port 80. Also, in a real world application is usual to have your servers behind a router, so even if the Kestrel server is listening in a port you may need to use a different port to connect to it.

Comment: Also check this, it may help: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639

Comment: @Gusman: Thank you. However, when I don't specify a port Kestrel claims it is listening on port 5000, not 80?

Comment: Well, you're right, the default port for Kestrel is 5000, that's your answer then :)

Comment: Thanks Gusman...but if Kestrel should choose a different one, how does that information make its way to the client so that it knows?

Comment: Read the link I added, there's explained how to tell Kestrel how to use different ports without messing with the code.